# VB Script for auto Login into website giving an error

Tags: vbscript

I am using below VB script for auto login in to website. It is entering username but it does not enter password and gives the error that 'doesn't support this property or method' . I have not worked in VB script , so not sure why this error is coming.

```
    On Error Resume Next
    Const PAGE_LOADED = 4
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Call objIE.Navigate("http://www.gmail.com")
    objIE.Visible = True
    Do Until objIE.ReadyState = PAGE_LOADED : Call WScript.Sleep(100) : Loop
    objIE.Document.all.username.Value = "username"
    objIE.Document.all.Passwd.Value = "password"
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    msgbox "Error: " & err.Description
    End If
    Call objIE.Document.all.login_form.submit
    Set objIE = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if this code can did the trick or not because gmail has changed its source code !

```
Dim IE
Set IE = Wscript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = 1 
IE.navigate("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=ig&passive=true&continue=http://www.google.com/ig%3Fhl%3Den&followup=http://www.google.com/ig%3Fhl%3Den&cd=US&hl=en&nui=1&ltmpl=default")
Do While (IE.Busy)
    WScript.Sleep 10
Loop
Set Helem = IE.document.getElementById("Email")
Helem.Value = "Your Login goes here" 'Change to your Gmail login 
Set Helem = IE.document.Forms(0)
Helem.Submit 
Do While (IE.Busy)
    WScript.Sleep 10
Loop
wscript.sleep 2000
Set Helem = IE.document.getElementById("Passwd") 
Helem.Value = "Your Password goes here" 'Change to your Gmail password
Set Helem = IE.document.Forms(0)
Helem.Submit
```

Comment: I want to login to multiple sites apart from Gmail. Another issues is that, I tried with WScript but it says ActiveX component can't create object : 'wsscript.shell'

Comment: @Coder157 it is `wscript.shell` and not `wsscript.shell` you have an extra `s`